# Shell script to delete semaphore file(Lock File) of the job if that job is not running

Tags: linux, shell

I want to write a shell script for deleting all lock files present in various directories.
I want to implement following logic.

- Check for lock file by directory by directory.
- If Lock file is found in particular Job directory, check whether that job is running.
- If Job is not running, delete the lock file.
- Move on to next directory.
- Follow the above procedure till the last Job directory.

*** Do I need to specify individual Job directory Lock file location?

Comment: Is this for a program you control, or just random lock files by other processes?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: what is a "job directory"? what do the lock filenames look like? what is your shell